# Don't see Mail System under Configuration

Tags: emails, configuration

I'm currently going through the prerequisites of Acquias configuring platform email
https://docs.acquia.com/cloud-platform/manage/platform-email/platform-email-configuration/#associate-domain

but I do not see the Mail System to check what our default Mail System is. Does this mean We are using a different one? I do see Nemo Integration but still expected to be able to access Mail System.

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you don't have the [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) module installed and enabled on your site. If you want to use only the default Drupal PhpMailer, then you don't need Mail System. You only need to use Mail System if you install a different mailer and want to use that different mailer.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way i can check and make sure i'm using the default Drupal PhpMailer?

Comment: Using drush from the command line, type `drush php-eval "foreach (\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')->getDefinitions() as \$plugin) {print_r(\$plugin['class'] . \"\n\");}" ` which will show you the *available* mailers. Drupal core provides Drupal\Core\Mail\Plugin\Mail\TestMailCollector and Drupal\Core\Mail\Plugin\Mail\PhpMail, and if you only see these and you can be sure that PhpMail is the only mailer in use. If you see other options, then some other module is providing a mailer which *may* be used.

Comment: thanks but i seem to be getting the below error `In Drupal.php line 130:

  \Drupal::$container is not initialized yet. \Drupal::setContainer() must be
   called with a real container.`